# Weierstrass Example

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I was reading the section of Lang's Complex Analysis about Weierstrass products, and came across this example:

[image]

I don't understand how the textbook got these results. So far in this section, I have read that

- If f is an entire function without zeros, there exists an entire function h such that $f(z) = e^{h(z)}$
- If $|z| \leq 1/2$, then $| \log E_n(z) |\leq 2|z|^n$
- The product $\Pi_{n=1}^\infty E_n(z,z_n) = \Pi_{n=1}^\infty (1-\frac{z}{z_n})e^{P_n(z/z_n)} $ converges uniformly and absolutely on every disc $|z| \leq R$ and defines an entire function with zeros at the points of the sequence $\{z_n\}$, and no other zeros

How did the author get to the conclusions in the example? I included these theorems since I assume they are used. If someone could provide clues or break it down for me, it would be much appreciated. Also any links to useful resources that explain Weierstrass products would be a help.

Comment: This is an example. Does Lang not derive them in the text? "We claim that ..." certainly suggests as much.

Comment: There are two underlying theorems : the easy one, $f(z)=\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi z)} -\sum_n \frac1{(z-n)^2}$ is a 1-periodic bounded entire function, thus it is constant $=f(i\infty)=0$. The more complicated one : $g(z)=\frac{\pi z}{\sin(\pi z)}\prod_{n\ge 1} (1-\frac{z^2}{n^2})$ is a non-vanishing entire function of growth bounded by $O(e^{C|z|})$ (the difficulty is that we don't anything about the growth of $1/g(z)$) thus $g(z) = e^{az+b}$ and looking at $g(0)$ and $g(i\infty)$ gives $g(z)=1$.

Comment: I'm sorry; yes, he provides a proof, but I don't follow it and it was a little too long to post. I was hoping for a clearer explanation here @TedShifrin